# Backbonejs gmail

Tags: backbone.js, gmail, openid

I am looking to figure out how to integrate gmail login with Backbonejs. Does anyone know where I can start? I am completely confused. Thanks!

Comment: Gmail oAuth is a server-side thing. Backbone has very little to do with it except for binding events on form submission. You should read more Gmail oAuth : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

Comment: In [this tutorial](http://dailyjs.com/2012/12/13/backbone-tutorial-3/) it's explained how to authenticate with oauth 2 and Backbone to access Gmail's tasks, I dunno if it's enough for your purpose, just check it out.

Comment: You like to use google login in your backbone website or to access the user gmail account and perform some tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Besides Ingro's suggestion, you could also create a simple web service (let's say with Java Jersey for example), and use the Java Mail API to connect to your account and retrieve your data using some Ajax calls from your Backbone client app.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail will require a server-side oauth call. I would recommend NodeJS as it has a ton of support for oAuth.